# Run command line after a Windows service has started

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-7-x64

I am using Windows 7 Enterprise 64 bit, and I need to get a command to run after a Windows service has started. The command is `java -jar ords.war` which starts Oracle's ORDS. The program can not be started until a service called OracleServiceXE has started. So, the program should wait for it to start first then run. Can I do that in Windows 7?

Comment: use [`NotifyServiceStatusChange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-notifyservicestatuschangea) on *OracleServiceXE* and exec *java.exe* with *java -jar ords.war* command line.

Comment: It looks like exactly what I need. But where to call that function? And it looks like a bit complex. It needs some dll files. Unfortunately, I do not have a deep knowledge of Windows technicals. I'd prefer if there is something easier.

Comment: *But where to call that function* - from any place in your code. *It needs some dll files* - no, may be i wrong understand you, but *NotifyServiceStatusChange* not need any dll.

Comment: There is no code I have written. The OracleServiceXE service starts automatically when Windows starts up.

Comment: may be you need write some code, if you want such functional. also i think *OracleServiceXE* begin executing not enough - it must complete self initialization and be ready for incoming calls. this already question about concrete program - how detect that it ready

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. The Java command should run after the service has completely started. I scheduled a task to run the Java command after 4 minutes because I noticed that the service takes about +3 minutes to completely start. It works but I did not want to hardcode time.